# How should I extend the Django FeinCMS MediaLibrary?

Tags: django, media-library, feincms

We would like to extend the `MediaLibrary` of the `Django` `FeinCMS` without editing the module code itself.

We want

- a few custom fields
- and to use a library for individual cropping that we have already.

How should we put everything together?

The simplest approach would be to create an extensions model with a `ForeignKey` to the `MediaLibrary`, and to register a custom Admin site with an inline admin for the extensions model. But maybe there's a cleaner and better way.

Comment: You can patch the Medialibrary model the same way you patch the Page model

Comment: You're right. And this sounds cleaner and better. Thanks! (I can only accept this as the correct answer if you post it as an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hedde said, the media file model supports registering extensions the same way as the page module allows, using `MediaFile.register_extensions`.

The method which is used for generating thumbnails in the media library *should* always be `FEINCMS_MEDIALIBRARY_THUMBNAIL`. The default value of this setting is `feincms.module.medialibrary.thumbnail.default_admin_thumbnail` which is a method that receives a media file object and returns the URL to a thumbnail or `None`.